# Recommendation For Tightening Wheel Stud

Tags: wheels, kia, lug-nut, stud

I have to replace a broken wheel stud in the rear of a kia Optima. 
I do not have an impact gun to tighten down the stud properly but I do have a torque wrench. The problem is that the hub will spin when trying to tighten it with a wrench.

So my question is, can I put the wheel back on, lower the car, and tighten the lug nut onto the stud to get it tightened? Is that a good way to do it or is that not recommended? It is the only way I would be able to get the stud tightened.

Comment: Can you get someone to press the brakes while you tighten it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:
Thanks to Alephzero's comment, now removed, I had to correct my answer :

If the stud is to be fitted into the hub, then the hub need to be "locked" or wedged to prevent rotation, with a bar wedged against a strong suspension point for example and the stud torqued into place using two nuts locked together on the threads.

Make sure the handbrake is on and/or the car is in gear or chocked to prevent movement - but that was done before jacking it up...

Comment: Thank you, I was needing reassurance because I didn't this this was best practice.

Comment: @alephzero good point, too early, not enough coffee, thanks.

Comment: Deleted my previous comment, since it leaving it would have implied that the correct method in the edited answer was wrong!

Answer (score 0):

I have only needed to do this on one wheel ( 6 studs) , but I simply tightened them to about 5 ftXlb. That held them in place , then when I put on the rim/tire and torqued it to about 80 ftXlb while on the ground , it pulled the studs into the wheel.